# Цикличный асинхронный запрос

Tags: ajax

Задача такая.  Есть веб страница, на которую нужно вывести информацию из бд, тогда, когда она там появится. Можно написать ajax запрос к php скрипту, который бы проверял есть ли в базе нужная информация и возвращал назад в ajax и поместить это в цикл, но мне кажется, что эта плохая реализация. Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: почему _кажется, что эта плохая реализация._?

Comment: Либо периодическими Ajax-запросами к серверу, либо через WebSocket.

Comment: Именно существование WebSocket или Long Polling меня смущает, так так WebSocket наверное больше подходит, но насколько я знаю, эта технология не очень стабильная и может работать/не работать в разных браузерах, серверах

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Comment: В вашей задаче достаточно будет использовать SSE. Нативная поддержка у него ниже чем у websocket, но для него есть много полифилов.

Comment: + [у sse меньше проблем с прокси серверами](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914374/server-sent-event-vs-web-sockets)